# Assetic: how to include javascript file only for dev environment?

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I want to add Javascript file that should be loaded in dev environment only, not in prod.

```
{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

How can I modify this example to disable it's loading in prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{{ app.environment }}`

Try this :

```
{% if app.environment == 'dev' %}
    {% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need.